2 Domains pointing to SIngle Wordpress , issues with links
I have two domains on wordpress site
site1.mybusiness.com and www.site1.com
The thing is i use this domain site1.mybusiness.com untill its fully operational witha ll plugins setip and site ready to go.
Then i want to use main domain www.site1.com for public use
Problem is i can visit the site as i use this in wp-config
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

But look like all links on site still point to  site1.mybusiness.com as this is inside wordpress database in wp options.
Is there any to make them work for multiple domains ?
The other thing is there are multiple plugins which register them via site URL like wordfence , google site kit , etc , how does people do it ?
